# Markdownのスポイラーでの装飾時、文章が隠れていることを分かるようにして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, デザイン, markdown

Markdownで「スポイラー」を使うと一部の文章を非表示に出来ますが、モバイル版では「クリックして文章を表示」とスポイラーが設定されていることが分かるようになっている一方、
PCで表示した際は一見なにも書かれていない引用ブロックがあるだけのように見えます。

投稿者が注意書きを添えればいいのかもしれませんが、モバイル版の挙動に合わせた方が分かりやすいのではないかと思います。

**PC版のスポイラー**
[image: PCで表示した際は一見なにも書かれていない引用ブロックがあるだけに見える]

**モバイル版のスポイラー**
[image: モバイル版では「クリックして文章を表示」とスポイラーが設定されていることが分かるようになっている]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2020-08 に MSE で投稿本文に関するデザインの改善についてのアナウンスがあり、スポイラーのデザインも変更されたようです。

[New post formatting - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446)

**変更後のデザイン:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]